# JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I need complete the function named seed that returns its arguments in an array. That is, if the function is called with three arguments (seed(a,b,c)) it should return an array containing the three arguments ([a,b,c]).

Comment: Please add what you have tried. This is directly asking for code, without any research. This is not a code providing service

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Array.from` to convert the [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) object to an array:

```js
function seed() {
    return Array.from(arguments);
}
```

Comment: how about `(...args) => args` ;)